# Setting CSS display doesn’t work

Tags: javascript, css

I am working with a captcha. Upon success I want to set the `display` of the `<div>` that includes the captcha to `"none"`. In that success part I have:

```
document.getElementById("mainForm").style.display="block"; 
document.getElementById("captcha").style.display="none";
alert("the captcha display is " + document.getElementById("captcha").style.display);
```

The resulting `alert` says that it is `"block"`, even though I have just set it to `"none"`.

Any idea why?

Comment: It should say `none`. Cannot reproduce this.

Comment: Create a fiddle to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Check your selectors - and provide your markup as it pertains to the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like your javascript code is working, so I don't see a problem. Maybe you should attach some css and html and make code snippet with the problem.

```js
document.getElementById("mainForm").style.display="block"; 
document.getElementById("captcha").style.display="none";
alert("the captcha display is " + document.getElementById("captcha").style.display);
```

```css
#mainForm {
  width: 320px;
  height: 180px;
  background: #00A;
}

#captcha {
  width: 160px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #0A0;
}
```

```html
<form id="mainForm">
  <div id="captcha">
  </div>
</form>
```

Regards, KJ